# Can authentication be done on more than one table(react/nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, backend

Iam going to do an online library management system

I have **3 roles **(stored in separate tables in the database)
The user: they have an interface that displays all the books online so they can preview() the front of the books, search() the books and reserve() the books online

The librarian: they have a totally different interface that allows them  to do the management (registering the users,adding/delete books/managing reservations..etc)

The admin : the one who have access to the whole database , and can manipulate it so for example if a librarian is fired he can omit them

My main question is about the authentication part
I said before that i have 3 roles (different tables in the database) , each one of them has a different interface
Is that type of authentication possible in the backend?
And in which framework/lang i can use?
I mean when the admin enters his email and pass , his own interface appears
And when the user enters his email and pass , the interface of books,reserving appears
And when the librarian open his email and pass , the management interface appears

Thanks in advance

I didn’t start developing yet this question encountered me while designing the database, so i was worried about that concern

- Because i am still studying the technology i will use nodejs/react so i was wondering of that type of authentication is possible?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “separate tables”. Users without have one or more roles. You can use those roles to do whatever you want on the front and back ends. It doesn’t change  how authentication or authorization works. Yes, it’s possible—but you may want to take a step back and look at existing solutions.

Comment: I mean they ared in the database in different tables , admin table ,user table, librarian table , they are not 3 roles in the user table

Comment: Why? Users are users. Separate tables is more brittle, less extensible, and IMO it's just confusing. Normalize your users and roles first.

Comment: because in my database , I have the "borrow" table , which stores the infromation of the user who borrowed the book (user id) and the libraraian who managed this borrowing (libararian id) , so in the "borrow" table we have to foriegn keys: user_id , librarian id. How would it be possible if they are both users

Comment: They're both people--one borrowing a book, one helping them borrow it. (Ignoring the reality of librarians checking books out to themselves.) Why keep them in different tables?

Comment: @DaveNewton because in the borrowing table i need to store two piece of information user id , librarian id , if they are both stored as users I cannot do that

Comment: @DaveNewton if i stored all users in "user table" and added the filed :role_id) where it is connected it with a table that has the roles(borrower/admin/librarian) , how would i store in the same record both the borrower that borrowed and the librarian that helped him do the borrowing?

Comment: Same way you’re doing it now but both ids are user ids. I don’t see what the issue is—this is how it’s done 99% of the time.

Comment: can i store the same foreign key twice in the same record? @DaveNewton

Comment: That could be tested by trying it. I don’t personally know of any database that disallows using the same foreign key in a single row *(assuming constraints are met)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally possible. You can assign a role to each user that helps you point them to the correct interface when needed.